# PowerBI: Using slicer to change date column into user local time

Tags: powerbi, timezone, dax

I have a dataset that uses Direct Query. I have a timestamp column and I am trying to add another column that will show the local time of that column for differnt users based on the selection from the slicer (which contains the list of countries). The new column should show the timezone based on the slicer list but I am not getting the right timezone.

I managed to connect to a timezonedb that will give me a list of offset for different timezones based on this article in this link: https://whitepages.tygraph.com/2020/10/dynamic-time-zone-conversion-using-power-bi/

This is what I have tried:

```
DAX measure: selected_offset = MAX(global_timezone[offset_days])
New column(local_time): date_column + [selected_offset]
 
**Start Timestamp: Timestamp column is saved using UTC+0
**selected_offset = SG timezone (UTC+8) = 0.3333

Error:
selected_offset = 0.583333 (instead of 0.3333)

Start Timestamp   selected_offset    local_time
04/13/2022 2:38  0.583333333     04/13/2022 16:38
04/13/2022 2:37  0.583333333     04/13/2022 16:37
04/13/2022 2:37  0.583333333     04/13/2022 16:37
 
Desired output: (see local_time column below)
 
Start Timestamp   selected_offset    local_time
04/13/2022 2:38  0.333333333     04/13/2022 10:38
04/13/2022 2:37  0.333333333     04/13/2022 10:37
04/13/2022 2:37  0.333333333     04/13/2022 10:37
```

Please let me know how to get the correct date time for local_time column based on slicer selection. Most solutions I found offer solution in Power Query which is something I cannot use at the moment due to DQ I am using for this dataset. Thanks!

Comment: What is your current problem? Did you get some errors?

Comment: The problem I get is the offset is 0.583333 and when I add the date column to the offset I get the local time wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are certain how this solution (from the article) is working.
First of all, we get the current UTC (UTC+0) from UTCNOW() function then we check the offset to other timezones. This means you should know what time zone your timestamp is from. You need to do two calculations, first subtract the offset from the "base column" and then add the offset to the desired time zone.

For example, if I want to show time for someone in America/Chicago and I have a column with the timestamp 2022-04-14 09:55 (UTC+2 Europe/Warsaw). Offset to this timezone is 0.08333. offset to America/Chicago -0.21

then full calculation is '2022-04-14 09:55' - (0.08333) + (-0.21)  == 2022-04-14 02:55